# Two-column itemization with title in each column

Tags: lists, titles, itemize, minipage, columns

I'd like to make a two-column list with some kind of titles, with "normal" text before and after. I tried it with the package "multicol" an with "minipage", neiter turned out well. Since the problem is hard to explain, have a look:

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \begin{document}

    \section{Messdaten}
    Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla.

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    First List:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{aaa}
    \item{bbb}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    Second List:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{ccc}
    \item{ddd}
    \item{eee}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}

    Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla.

    \end{document}
```

I'd like "First List" and "Second List" on the same height, and not so near to the upper Blabla. The items can but don't have to have different distances from each other. The item "ccc" is too near to the bottom Blabla.
Truth is, my very approach is not clever, but unfortunately I don't know any better. ;)
Help requested.

Comment: Just use the optional paramater to `minipage`: `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}` to specify `t`op alignment, for _both_ `minipage`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using `t` for the optional argument of both `minipage`s (**t**op alignment), suppressing a spurious blank space (after the first `\end{minipage}`) and adding some vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

 \section{Messdaten}
Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla.\par\medskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    First List:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{aaa}
    \item{bbb}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    Second List:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{ccc}
    \item{ddd}
    \item{eee}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\par\bigskip

Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is just perfect. I tend to underestimate optional arguments. :)